# Firebase 3.3 broke notifications iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-notifications

Hey guys my app works fine if I am using 3.2. On 3.2 I gather the `[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]` and I send a notification from the firebase console. Works great.

However on 3.3 I attempt the same and it gives me a token but never receives the message. I double checked to make sure notification permissions are accepted etc.. But no dice.

edit** upon inspection FirebaseInstanceID 1.0.7 seems to be the culprit here.

Anyone else seeing this problem? Code below

```
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];
}

- (void)connectToFcm 
{
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue even if you generate a new Instance ID token?

Comment: I perform a clean install and get the new id. doesnt work. If i downgrade FB to 3.2 get an id. Use it and it works. Upgrade to 3.3 and use that token all is well. Not Sure what is going on

Comment: Could you report your issue here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features where you can provide more information

Comment: Bug report has been sent.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing.  For a targeted fix you can keep the latest Firebase/Messaging pod and add: pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '1.0.6' until the problem is fixed.